# Remove identical succesive characters from string PHP

Tags: php, loops

I have this string

```
$string = "000000014Y00j:7";
```

I want to turn it into

```
$string = "14Y00j:7";
```

I want to remove all the zeros from the start of the string, in PHP

Comment: `$string = ltrim($string,'0');`

Comment: How do I pick your comment as the answer, Mark Baker? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete any chars (not only 0) you could use

```
$a = "000000014Y00j:7";
if($a[0]==$a[1]){
 $a = ltrim($a,$a[0]);
}
echo $a;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "000000014Y00j:7"; 
$str = ltrim($str, '0');

echo $str ;
```

Comment: if i had to take a guess I'd say it's because it looks like someone copied the OP comment for some easy rep

Comment: well I confirm I did not copied it just before adding the code I was testing it on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and by the time I added it it was already there in the comment..

Comment: perhaps if you pointed to a timestamped link to relevant code I'd count that as confirmation. In any case, you posted a full 2 minutes after the comment. Hard to believe it was "accident" or "coincidence" but even it was, the honorable thing to do would be to fall on your sword and delete

Comment: Come on guys, it's not like it's impossible for two people to come up with the same answer to a ridiculously simple question like this.

Comment: @Sammitch right. it's a ridiculously simple question that deserves to be closed as a dupe. Which is very likely why made a comment instead of an answer. w/e

Comment: well I would choose not to delete it.. may be someday it might help someone. vote up/down are just part and parcel of this site :)